# Using a third-party abstract class as if it were an interface?

Tags: java, polymorphism

In a 3rd party library I'm using, there is the following bit of hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    // Class is public in the Java sense and public in the library's API
}

public class FooImpl extends Foo
{
    // While this class is public in the Java sense, it is
    // NOT part of the public API and is not even documented
    // Library functions that hand back instances of this class
    // hand them back as type Foo
}
```

Various methods in the library operate on things of type `Foo`.  The `Foo` docs say users can extend `Foo` to make a concrete implementation and (obviously) the library provides a concrete implementation.

I am happy with the library-provided implementation except for one method, whose behavior I would like to change a bit.  But the hierarchy I'm provided with is tripping me up.

**If** `Foo` was an interface (which it isn't!), I'd just do this:

```
public FooWrapper implements Foo
{
    private Foo wrappedImpl;

    public FooWrapper(Foo toBeWrapped) {
        wrappedImpl = toBeWrapped;
    }

    List<Whatever> methodIWantToTweak() {
        List<Whatever> list = wrappedImpl.methodIWantToTweak();
        do_something_to_list(list);
        return list;
    }

    Something methodThatsOk() {
        return wrappedImpl.methodThatsOk();
    }

    // similar delegations for remaining methods
}
```

But since it's **not** an interface I can't do this, or at least can't do it as cleanly.

The only things I can think of doing are:

1) Extend the API-non-public class FooImpl and override the method I want to tweak.

2) Do something like:

```
public class FooWrapper extends Foo
{
    private Foo wrappedImpl;

    public FooWrapper(Foo toBeWrapped) {
        super();
        wrappedImpl = toBeWrapped;
    }

    List<Whatever> methodIWantToTweak() {
        List<Whatever> list = wrappedImpl.methodIWantToTweak();
        do_something_to_list(list);
        return list;
    }

    Something methodThatsOk() {
        return wrappedImpl.methodThatsOk();
    }

    // Override all non-final public, protected, and package-local
    // methods and delegate them to wrappedImpl
}
```

Both those approaches smell like heck to me.  The first has the problem that it depends on a class it's not supposed to know about and which could be changed/disappear/be renamed in future versions of the library.  The second has the problem that the superclass piece of `FooWrapper` isn't actually used, and that it's impossible to override any final or private methods of `Foo` (which will cause problems as in those cases one is unable to delegate to `wrappedImpl`).

I guess I'll have to go with the first approach, since at least it'd give correct behavior, whereas the second will likely be broken in potentially evil, subtle ways depending on the internal details of `Foo`.

Am I just out of luck, then?  What other approaches/ideas am I overlooking?

Comment: Why can you not override the method that you would like to tweak? You could provide the same implementation, except you'd call base instead wrappedImpl. Am I missing something?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - What you might be missing is that the OP may not be able to change the code that creates Foo instances to make it create an instance of *his* Foo subclass.  Wrappering can potentially work around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any other approach that wouldn't be far more smelly!  (Reflection would work, but in this case it would be worse than the problem you are trying to avoid.)

I think that the second approach is the best.  If the `Foo` abstract class is designed as a public class, then it *shouldn't* have nasty internal details that might trip you up.  If it does, they've got the design wrong.

Note that since you are creating a wrapper class for "real" Foo instances:

- You can probably ignore most of the functionality that the abstract class provides for "real" Foo subclasses to use.
- You can probably ignore any state represented by Foo-level attributes.
- You could stub out methods in the API that you don't need to use in your application; e.g. code them to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

All of these help to reduce the complexity of your problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to override any of `Foo`'s final or protected (see below) methods, I'd go with the second approach: treat `Foo` as an interface and do what you'd do in that case.  The advantage is that you are not dependent on the `FooImpl` that can change.

`final` and `private` methods of `Foo` are not a problem, since you would not be able to override those in `FooImpl` or if `Foo` was an interface, anyway.  Also, I think you meant `protected` instead of `private`.

If you *do* need to override `protected` methods, you will need to go with your first approach.

Comment: The issue with `final` (whatever the visibility) and `private` methods of `Foo` as I see it, is that if called they will be the superclass's methods and will run in the context of the superclass piece of my class instead of using the state, etc. of the `wrappedImpl` object for the real work.  So overridden methods depend on the state of `wrappedImpl` but non-overridden methods depend on the state of the superclass piece of the instance of my `FooWrapper` object.

Comment: The final and private methods cannot be overriden in impl. either, so that should not be a problem. protected methods are a bit tricker, but if you _always_ delegate to the impl.(1) then the impl.'s protected version will be called (from the impl.'s called public method). (1) tweaking return values do not count;  It is true that you will have to override _all_ public/protected non-final methods of the abstract base class to ensure proper delegation to impl.